# How do you detect colliding divs in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, collision-detection

How do you detect multiple div elements that collide using JQuery? I've [found a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/nGRwt/7/), but it only detects two elements. How would you pass multiple div IDs into that function?

**HTML:**

```
<strong>Drag divs around.</strong>

<div id="div1">
    Div1
</div><br/>
<div id="div2">
    Div2
</div>

<p>Colliding? <span id="result">false</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 { width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: pink; }
#div2 { width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: green; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
}


window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#result').text(collision($('#div1'), $('#div2')));
}, 200);


$('#div1,#div2').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be a good idea to reuse your own `collision` method, but to go over each possible combination of divs that can collide:

```
function collision_() {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y < arguments.length; y++) {
                if (x == y) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (collision(arguments[x], arguments[y])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is not as optimal as it can be, but it gets the job done.  If you want it to be even more optimal, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/nGRwt/132/

Answer (score 0):

you can pass any number or parameters into a function and then within it use the `arguments` keyword which is an array of all passed in arguments:

```
function doStuff(){
  for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    //Do stuff with arg now.
  }
}
```

---

Also, the `.draggable()` in jQuery UI has the ability to stack items, is that your ultimate goal here?

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class='box'>Div1</div>
<div id="div2" class='box'>Div2</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.box').draggable({stack: '.box'});
```

I've made a demo with that example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/nGRwt/134/